# Bulk insert in a specific column in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, bulkinsert

I have a table `dic` that has 2 columns `english` and `bangla`. I want to insert data into only the `bangla` column using bulk insertion from a text file.

I tried which can insert into 2 column

```
BULK INSERT dic
FROM 'C:\Users\Imon-Bayazid\Desktop\wordddd\good one\test.txt'
WITH
(
   FIELDTERMINATOR = '\n',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

But how can I do into one specific column???

Comment: Is your english column NOT NULL?

Comment: You want insert or update the column? Also show table scheme.

Comment: english or bangla column may have null value ...@BhushanFirake

Comment: i want to insert a huge data on that table @HamletHakobyan

Comment: Please, provide both table and text file structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map from fields in the source file to fields in the destination table using a [format file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129.aspx).

I assume you know that bulk insert is for inserting new rows only, not for updates.

So you might have a format file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT 
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\n"/>
  ... other fields?
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="bangla"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Any other columns in table 'dic' would need to be nullable or have default values.

You then specify the format file as an option of the BULK INSERT statement

```
BULK INSERT dic
FROM 'C:\Users\Imon-Bayazid\Desktop\wordddd\good one\test.txt'
WITH
(
   FIELDTERMINATOR = '\n',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
   FORMATFILE = 'path to my format file.xml'
)
```

Comment: i dont understand how and where to use your above code ?? I used my code and just put them  into visual stdio 2010 query . @Phil

Comment: Do you have SQL Server Management Studio?  You need to create a  format file on disk, e.g. C:\Users\Imon-Bayazid\Desktop\wordddd\good one\format.xml and reference that in your bulk insert.

Comment: no i haven't this.i am just using visual stdio 10 which has default sql server

Comment: Where to save the  format file???? i am using vs10 where do i save the formate file in vs10???

Comment: Save the format file anywhere you want and then specify the path e.g. FORMATFILE = 'C:\Users\Imon-Bayazid\Desktop\wordddd\good one\format.xml'

Comment: can you write the full format file for my case?? it would be helpful for me as i m new to this.@Phil

Comment: @ImonKuet: **YOU** should show some research effort, too! Read the MSDN docs that Phil pointed you to (link in his answer) - and then **TRY YOURSELF** to write that format file! It's really **not that hard** - just give it a try!

Comment: i tried but there is an error.my format file was like this <?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT 
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" TERMINATOR="\n"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="b"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>  but there is an error like "Attribute TERMINATOR could not be specified for this type"

Comment: If your fields have field terminators then they need to be type CharTerm or NCharTerm.  Refer to the definition of xml format files at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187833.aspx and pay attention to required/optional attributes.